# How to link to Home page from sub folder?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have the following in `views/page2/index.cshtml`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Continue...", "Home");
```

I'd like the above to link to the root Home controller's view. What I get now is `localhost/page2/home/` instead of `localhost/`.

Any ideas how to use the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you do not need to use the html helper to generate the link. Use pure html.

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

This link will link to the root of your web application.

Comment: That's what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for the [`ActionLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper_ActionLink_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) looks like this:

```cs
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent ActionLink (
  string linkText, 
  string actionName, 
  string controllerName, 
  string protocol, 
  string hostname, 
  string fragment, 
  object routeValues, 
  object htmlAttributes);
```

So when you call `@Html.ActionLink("Continue...", "Home");` you are passing in the `linkText` and the `actionName`. Since this is all the router has to work with, it assumes the `actionName` you want (`Home`) is within the same Controller as the current page.

In order to tell the router that you want to switch to another Controller, you need to pass that Controller name in as well.

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Controller");
```

I'm going to assume that when you're passing in `Home` you actually wanted to reach the `Index` action from the `Home` controller. If so, this would look like this:

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Continue...", "Index", "Home");
```